# Extract authors name from a bibtex entry

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have a bibtex list of references and i would like to get the authors' names from a specific entry in my `.bib` file. Is there a command for that?

Comment: Something like `\getauthorname{<bibentry>}`?

Comment: Related: [Command line tool to extract `.bib` entry by key?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81925/5764)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `natbib` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{docuemnt}

\citeauthor{smith90}

\bibliography{bibliography.bib}
\end{document}
```

See here: http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php